# How can I specify variables from using data that I don't want to keep in a merge?

Tags: stata

Suppose  I have two datasets and want to `merge` them.

```
merge 1:1 key using "$root/datasetB"
```

datasetB has many variables but i don't want to keep a specific one, let's say: `unwanted_var`

I know I could just write down all the variables that I do want in the option `keepusing`, but is there a way to put  in the `merge` command the variables from using data that I **don't want to keep**? That would save me a lot of typing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's some technique, applied to the `use` command rather than to the `merge` command, but the principle is the same in either case.

```
. sysuse auto, clear
(1978 Automobile Data)

. tempfile autodata

. save `autodata'
file /var/folders/xr/lm5ccr996k7dspxs35yqzyt80000gp/T//S_31836.000001 saved

. ds
make          mpg           headroom      weight        turn          gear_ratio
price         rep78         trunk         length        displacement  foreign

. clear

. quietly describe using `autodata', varlist

. local allvars `r(varlist)'

. local dropvars gear_ratio

. local keepvars : list allvars - dropvars

. use `keepvars' using `autodata' 
(1978 Automobile Data)

. ds
make          mpg           headroom      weight        turn          foreign
price         rep78         trunk         length        displacement

.
```